# Triangle Inequality for $\mathcal{C}^1$-norm

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

> For $f \in \mathcal{C}^1\left([a,b]\right)$ prove that
>
> $$|||f||| = \text{sup}\left\{|f(x)| : x \in [a,b]\right\} + \text{sup}\left\{|f'(x)| : x \in (a,b)\right\},$$
>
> is in fact a norm on $\mathcal{C}^1\left([a,b]\right)$.

I've proved all the necessary properties, but I have a question regarding satisfying the triangle inequality.

I have that for $f,g \in \mathcal{C}^1\left([a,b]\right)$

$$\text{sup}(f + g) \leq \text{sup}(f) + \text{sup}(g). \tag{1}$$

Then using this fact

$$\begin{align}
|||f + g||| &= \text{sup}\left\{|f(x) + g(x)|\right\} + \text{sup}\left\{|f'(x) + g'(x)|\right\} \\
&\leq \text{sup}\left\{|f(x)| + |g(x)|\right\} + \text{sup}\left\{|f'(x)| + |g'(x)|\right\} \tag{By T.I.} \\
&\leq \text{sup}\left\{|f(x)|\right\} + \text{sup}\left\{|f'(x)|\right\} + \text{sup}\left\{|g(x)|\right\} + \text{sup}\left\{|g'(x)|\right\} \tag{By 1}\\
&=|||f||| + |||g|||.
\end{align}$$

Does (1) still hold here? If not how else would one go about showing this?

Comment: Yes, I think (1) still hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equation $(1)$ does hold true: for a point $x \in[a, b] $, we certainly have that
\begin{equation}
(f+g)(x) = f(x) + g(x) \leq \sup_{y \in [a,b]} f(y) + g(x) \leq \sup_{y \in [a,b]} f(y) + \sup_{y \in [a,b]}g(y)\, .
\end{equation}
Since $x$ was chosen arbitrarily, this is inequality is valid for all $x \in [a,b]$ and hence equation (1) holds.

Note that continuity of $f$ and $g$ is not needed here.